# jersey-media-multipart getting different exceptions: NoSuchMethod, ClassNotFound

Tags: java, maven, server, jersey, jax-rs

I'm trying to use jersey-media-multipart: 2.7 but I'm getting different error. Last one was:

```
dic 13, 2016 5:47:56 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase modified
GRAVE:     Resource '/WEB-INF/lib/hk2-locator-2.2.0.jar' is missing
dic 13, 2016 5:47:56 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFORMACIÓN: Ha comenzado la recarga de Contexto [/ACSU]
dic 13, 2016 5:47:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFORMACIÓN: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
dic 13, 2016 5:47:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
GRAVE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/glassfish/hk2/utilities/cache/ComputationErrorException
    at org.jvnet.hk2.external.generator.ServiceLocatorGeneratorImpl.initialize(ServiceLocatorGeneratorImpl.java:68)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.external.generator.ServiceLocatorGeneratorImpl.create(ServiceLocatorGeneratorImpl.java:103)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorFactoryImpl.internalCreate(ServiceLocatorFactoryImpl.java:270)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorFactoryImpl.create(ServiceLocatorFactoryImpl.java:230)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorFactoryImpl.create(ServiceLocatorFactoryImpl.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections._createLocator(Injections.java:142)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.createLocator(Injections.java:127)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:303)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:311)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:358)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1282)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1195)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1085)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5610)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:4088)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.backgroundProcess(WebappLoader.java:425)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1342)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1543)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1553)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1553)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1521)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.ComputationErrorException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1858)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1701)
    ... 27 more

dic 13, 2016 5:47:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
GRAVE: Servlet [Jersey REST Service] in web application [/ACSU] threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.ComputationErrorException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1858)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1701)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.external.generator.ServiceLocatorGeneratorImpl.initialize(ServiceLocatorGeneratorImpl.java:68)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.external.generator.ServiceLocatorGeneratorImpl.create(ServiceLocatorGeneratorImpl.java:103)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorFactoryImpl.internalCreate(ServiceLocatorFactoryImpl.java:270)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorFactoryImpl.create(ServiceLocatorFactoryImpl.java:230)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorFactoryImpl.create(ServiceLocatorFactoryImpl.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections._createLocator(Injections.java:142)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.createLocator(Injections.java:127)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:303)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:311)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:358)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1282)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1195)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1085)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5610)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:4088)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.backgroundProcess(WebappLoader.java:425)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1342)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1543)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1553)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1553)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1521)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

dic 13, 2016 5:47:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFORMACIÓN: Se ha completado la recarga de este Contexto
```

POM file has the following dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxrs-ri</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/javax.mail-api -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.36</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-jaxb</artifactId>
            <version>2.25</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.metaparadigm/json-rpc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.metaparadigm</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-rpc</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
            <artifactId>hk2-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0-b10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
            <artifactId>hk2-locator</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
            <artifactId>hk2-utils</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0-b10</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

I have removed and added different dependencies without success. Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you using `jersey-media-jaxb` version 2.25 when everything else Jersey is 2.7? That is probably the cause of the problem. And (unless you need that specific version) get rid of all the hk2 dependencies. The are pulled in by Jersey

Comment: Thanks! Yes I've started again and found the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I removed all the new libraries and added them again. So I noticed I didn't need to add hk2 libraries.

Even that I couldn't upgrade jaxb to 2.7 the project is working again.

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxrs-ri</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/javax.mail-api -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.36</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-jaxb</artifactId>
            <version>2.25</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.metaparadigm/json-rpc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.metaparadigm</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-rpc</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```